# Getting rid of loops for appending character vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

I am super new to R but have some experience with coding in EViews. From the post I have been reading on this site, I understand that loops can usually be replaced by faster codes in R. 
So, here's my question: I am trying to get a vector of characters in R. Each "character" will be a variable name made up of a country code and a variable. 
So If I have two countries and three variables, I would need a vector of 2x3=6 characters.
This is code I came up with:

```
list_pgo=character(0)
for (y in allb){ ###concept code a b c 
for (x in cty){ ###country code fr us
tempb <- paste(x,"pgo",y,"_id",sep="") ##variable name should be xpgoy_id
list_pgo<-append(list_pgo,tempb,after=length(list_pgo)) ### result should be something like frpgoa_id uspgoa_id frpgob_id uspgob_id frpgoc_id uspgoc_id   
}
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you want. Many functions in R are already vectorised (such as `paste`), meaning that they accept vectors and perform element-wise operations with R's usual reuse/repeat rules if the vector lengths do not match.

```
# Define your toy data (as character vectors)
allb <- c("a", "b", "c")
cty <- c("fr", "us")

# Get all combinations
all.comb <- expand.grid(x = allb, y = cty)

# Combine columns of generated matrix
list_pgo <- paste0(all.comb$x, "pgo", all.comb$y, "_id")
print(list_pgo)
#[1] "apgofr_id" "bpgofr_id" "cpgofr_id" "apgous_id" "bpgous_id" "cpgous_id"
```

**Edit:** Other ways and methods of course exists, but functions that already are vectorised are often much faster than the apply-family of functions that can be considered to be "loop-hiding" only.

Comparing the above to the one-liner in the comments:

```
library("microbenchmark")

fun1 <-function() {
  all.comb <- expand.grid(x = allb, y= cty)
  paste0(all.comb$x,"pgo",all.comb$y,"_id")
}

fun2 <- function() {
  apply(expand.grid(allb,cty), 1, function(x) paste(x[1],"pgo",x[2],"_id",sep=""))
}

microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2())
#Unit: microseconds
#   expr    min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
# fun1()  88.80 136.7705 185.3204 150.1570 163.098 3722.469   100
# fun2() 246.32 286.9275 353.2598 305.8925 326.419 4920.156   100
```

Comment: Or in one line: `apply(expand.grid(x,y), 1, function(x) paste(x[1],"pgo",x[2],"_id",sep=""))`

Comment: @ulfelder Sure, but I find that code much less easy to understand (especially for someone new to R). Not to mention that I also believe it to be slower in almost all cases. See the edit.